# Laravel 5.2 Dropdowns with Eloquent Lists Method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am pulling some values (`$citylist = User::lists('city');`) from my DB to display them as a dropdown list.

This is my view:

```
{!!Form::open(array('action' => 'PagesController@menue', 'method' => 'GET', 'style' => 'display: inherit;'))!!}
    {!! Form::select('city', $citylist, null, array('class' => 'selectpicker input-group-btn form-control', 'data-style' => 'btn-info btn-info btn-block')) !!}
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        {!!Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info'))!!}
    </span>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

After submitting the form there is a redirect. I am appending a city name as a query string to the url. So I get something like `.../menues/?city=london`.
However, since I am pulling the values with Eloquent's `lists()` method the ID is appended to the url instead of the city name.
So I get something like `.../menues/?city=1` instead of `.../menues/?city=london`.

I need the city name. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to build list like this (I'm using `pluck()` since `lists()` is deprecated):

```
$citylist = User::pluck('city', 'city');
```

Comment: Perfect, as always! Thanks